# VM running out of memory despite java has a ton for free heap

Tags: java, g1gc

My tomcat **Java 8** application is running with **24GB XMX** on **32GB** Virtual machine with **G1 GC**. It processes large files. Files have size of **5-7 GBs**.

After deployment during the processing of one of such files VM is starting to use **> 90%** of allocated memory. This value never drops and only increases despite the processing was over and Java has a ton of unused heap (**~7GBs**).

It however dropped once we triggered **Full GC** from the VisualVM. **We've also noticed the application had only one Major GC during its lifetime - which was triggered with Full GC from VisualVM**.

It's clear that java has committed heap and don't wan't to give it back to OS.

**Question is**: how to get rid of such behavior and return memory back to OS(looks like G1 doesn't do it until java 12) or how to investigate why remaining 8 GBs of non-heap space are full? seems like I can't do it with VisualVM.